# VBA - Date and Time, Clean and Format

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, format

I have imported data from Outlook into the Sheet, in `Column E` which has the part of the Body of Email i.e., the Order Date and Time. The column is in the format - `"yyyy-mm-dd h-mm"`. But, the cell contains extra line. I have tried to use - `CLEAN()`, `SUBSTITUTE()`, `REPLACE()` nothing worked.
When I manually edit the cell, by pressing backspace twice, the blanks are removed and the formats are applied automatically.

How do I do this for 30,000 rows?

Comment: Try: `TRIM(CLEAN(A1))`

Comment: I did, but it displays the cell vale as January 20, 2020 12:50 PM. I would rather like it to be displayed as "2020-01-20 12:50 PM". The format is applied.

Comment: Then try: `=--TRIM(CLEAN(A1))` and format the cell properly.